# Deploying project with a docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, web-deployment

I have a project . It has a folder docker. Please tell me how to deploy an existing project with the help of a docker? Is there a good tutorial? All I've found is installing a project using a docker, for a new project, but I need to install the project which i cloned from git.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question.

You might start with [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/). That'd be a fairly modern and easy starting point. There are many more tools than this, but I personally use GitLab as this is a all-in-one and user-friendly tool.

If the above doesn't suit you then please be more specific on what kind of project this is (language, framework), what git do you use (GitLab/GitHub/?), what kind of CI/CD tools would you want to use (Ansible, Gitlab CI, Heroku, ...).